# Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer Exam

Tags: magento2, certification

What is **Mage Titans MX - Certification Promo** discount in **Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer Exam** certification ?

[image]

Comment: I think this is only for taking attention for developers who want to give Magento 2 certification.

Comment: yes. but seems strange.

Comment: @all could you please tell me how come you know that this is free of charge?

Comment: I think it's mistake from magento itself.

Comment: Reply from Magento: `The exam is not free and there was a glitch in the system. We will be deleting all those purchases from the system. If you wish to register for the exam you will need to purchase the exam.`

Answer (score 4):

Mage Titans MX is a conference in Mexico. Magento offered certifications **at the conference** for attendees, apparently with a 100% discount.

Currently a similar promotion is offered for Imagine attendees at https://magento.wufoo.com/forms/imagine-2018-certification-registration/ (50% off all Magento 2 certifications)

Comment: Okay. So is it not applicable for India ?

Comment: No, this is not for any regular certification sites, just for the conference

Comment: @FabianSchmengler are you sure is not applicable for India?