# Magento 2 Certification

Tags: magento2, certification

Why there is no option to register for `Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer Exam` in webassessor account.

[image]

Comment: Yes, today Magento give us free Magento certification order. But they don't give vouchers. Also not listed exam name in webassessor. I think this is only for taking attention for developers who want to give Magento 2 certification.

Comment: @PrincePatel Right. I am facing same problem. I also posted checkout 
 screenshot here https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/219149/6084

Comment: Free order means :) @PrincePatel

Comment: @KeyurShah coupon code will automatically be applied of $160. So subtotal will be $0

Comment: Do you have the link for this so I can check? @PrincePatel

Comment: @KeyurShah It is full discount of $195. You can see here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219149/magento-2-certified-associate-developer-exam

Comment: @KeyurShah Click on purchase exam voucher: https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-associate-developer-exam Please check that you have only one item in cart. See the screenshot: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219149/magento-2-certified-associate-developer-exam

Comment: @PrincePatel However it is applicable for Mexico event participates only at Mexico.

Comment: I think there is some mistake over there @PrincePatel Kishan

Comment: @KeyurShah, Mage Titans MX is a conference in Mexico. Magento offered certifications at the conference for attendees, apparently with a 100% discount.

Comment: Reply from Magento: `The exam is not free and there was a glitch in the system. We will be deleting all those purchases from the system. If you wish to register for the exam you will need to purchase the exam.`

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find complete details:

1.[Magento 2 Professional  Certification Details](https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer#.Wpp5M0jhWnO)

[image]

2.[Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer](https://magento.wufoo.com/forms/imagine-2018-certification-registration/)

[image]

Comment: I am looking for Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer Exam

Comment: The link you sent is for PROFESSIONAL DEVELOPER

Comment: @KishanPatadia sorry for inconvenience